# How to send struct with Photon

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, photon

I'm creating a card game turn-based with photon for a school project, but  idk how to send the struct message, that includes structs card and Hand, 
can anyone solve my problem? Is necessary  use Photon.RegysterType()? I have tried to find something, but i don't find much, and the photon doc about serialization of custom type with Photon.RegysterType() I don't understand much.

Thank for the answer :)

There's the list of structs:

```
struct card
{
     internal string suit;
     internal string value;
}

struct Hand
{
     internal card[] hand;
     internal bool[] FinishedCards;
}

struct Message
{
     internal Hand Local, Remote;
     internal List Table, Deck;
     internal List StackLocal, StackRemote;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is one way:
    [Serializable]
    struct card
    {
         public string suit;
         public string value;
    }

    [Serializable]
    struct Hand
    {
         public card[] hand;
         public bool[] FinishedCards;
    }

    [Serializable]
    struct Message
    {
         public Hand Local, Remote;
         public List<card> Table, Deck;
         public List<card> StackLocal, StackRemote;
    }
...
view.RPC(nameof(RPCAcceptHand),Photon.Pun.RpcTarget.All,JsonUtility.ToJson(m) );
```